# Как изменить текст, который показывается при добавление файлов в комментариях?

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет, может кто сталкивался с такой задачей. Нужно мне изменить текст, который показывается над кнопкой добавления файлов при комментариях, например, товаров. Как на скриншоте.

https://www.screencast.com/t/WL3FgC2A

Comment: Картинки должны быть в теле вопроса. Но этого текста не в ВП, это какой-то плагин

Comment: Ищите в теме, родительской теме или в  плагинах